# How to fix the DVD lense PS2 voltage?

Tags: ps2

I still have my PS2 and I decided to play some of my old favorite games. It only plays CD games, so it plays anything PS1 and some PS2 games such as Half-Life as they are CD games. The PS2 does not read DVD disks. I have already taken it apart, and was able to fix the CD voltage, but not the DVD voltage, and I don't remember it's original position. I have the slim PS2, and I've been turning it for the past several hours.

How do I find the original position for the DVD voltage, and play my favorite DVD games again?
[image]

Answer (score 5):

Looking at various FAQs and instructional guides, including [IGN](http://www.ign.com/faqs/2003/ps2-disc-read-error-faq-390535) and [GameFaqs](http://www.gamefaqs.com/ps2/915821-playstation-2/faqs/19658), All of them said to start trying to find where the discs will read again by turning counter-clockwise by roughly 2 degrees each time up to about a 20 degree change. If that doesn't work, return to the starting position. (An easy way to keep track is to take some sort of marker, like a sharpie, and put a dot at the 12 o'clock position on the screw) If turning counter-clockwise didn't work, next was to go clockwise by 2 degrees at a time, up to roughly 20 degrees. If neither directions worked, next instruction was to repeat both directions, increasing the maximum, For instance, going up to 26 degrees instead of 20. Nowhere could I find a default degree. Just remember to go counter-clockwise first as that decreases the voltage and giving the laser too much may render it useless.

Comment: The problem is that I already turned this over a lot of times (a lot more than 20 degrees), I am really not sure about the original position. Is there a way to measure this voltage without putting everything back together all the time? (I have PS2 Slim)

Comment: I would imagine there is some kind of voltage meter out there that'll work, however I was not able to find one.

Comment: Also, if you turned the DVD voltage too far to the right you may have blown out the laser.

Comment: Yes, but the CD laser still works and it's all in one laser.

Comment: I don't know what to tell you then, I've looked further into fixing it and the most I've gotten is what's posted in the answer.